# Can we use 'be' after 'wish' to express a wish?

Tags: grammaticality

Of late, I came across a writing in which the writer has written, **'I wish you be a good human.'**
Is this correct to say **I wish you be......?**

Your take on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the *subjunctive*. Here is one source:

The subjunctive mood in English is a clause type used in some contexts which describe non-actual possibilities, e.g. "It's crucial that you be here" and "It's crucial that he arrive early." In English, the subjunctive is syntactic rather than inflectional, since there is no specifically subjunctive verb form. Rather, subjunctive clauses recruit the bare form of the verb.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)

From this viewpoint your sentence is correct. It reflects the first Wikipedia example. Other acceptable forms of the thought include *I wish you were ...*, *I wish you would be ...*.

Comment: The negative and mute downmarker  tells the questioner nothing useful. Why not explain yourself?